# Причина использования повелительного наклонения в условном предложении

Tags: лексика, грамматика, согласование

Мы можем выразить условие в прошлом (то, что в английском языке называется *counterfactual conditional*) двумя способами:

1. С помощью оборота «если бы — то»: *если бы я был дома, то не пропустил бы звонок*.
2. С помощью формы, похожей на повелительное наклонение: *будь я дома — не пропустил бы звонок*.

Меня интересует второй способ. Почему в условной конструкции используется именно повелительное наклонение? Ведь здесь отсутствует даже намёк на приказ или требование.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что наклонение глагола показывает отношение к действительности, а оно у повелительного и условного одинаковое.

лингвист А. А. Потебня сказал: «Сходство между наклонением условным и повелительным состоит в том, что оба они выражают не действительное событие, а идеальное, т. е. представляемое существующим только в мысли говорящего».

А. А. Потебня прав, ведь глаголы в условном и повелительном наклонении не изменяются по временам, поэтому обозначают действия, желаемые или возможные при определенных условиях, т.е. ирреальные.

Побудительные предложения в форме условного наклонения в основном употребляются тогда, когда нужно, чтобы конкретное лицо (говорящий, собеседник, 3-е лицо) совершило определенное действие. Предложения с формой повелительного наклонения также могут выражать это значение. Следовательно, в том и другом случаях эти выражения бывают близкими, почти тождественными: Отдохни немножко и Отдохнул бы ты немножко

Будь дома! - повеление, желание, ирреальное действие.

Будь я дома — не пропустил бы звонок. Будь = если б я был - действие ирреальное, в мыслях, но не в действительности.

Answer (score 2):

**Буде я дома — не пропустил бы звонок.**

**Среди союзов в придаточных условных предложениях, есть союз БУДЕ с пометкой устар.** В литературе 18-19 века он часто использовался, но и в современных текстах тоже встречается с дополнительным значением иронии, как это часто бывает с такими словами.

1) Ни леты мои, ни чин, ни положение ещё не позволили мне показать прямой неустрашимости, **буде** есть во мне она. [Д. И. Фонвизин. Недоросль (1782)]

В нем указывалось, что великая княгиня Ольга приняла святое крещение, но обряд сей следует повторить в Царьграде, **буде** княгиня Ольга туда приедет. [Борис Васильев. Ольга, королева русов (2002)]

А **буде** кто учнёт работу работать в воскресные дни, и его поймать, приводить в съезжую избу… да бить батоги». [И. Грачёва. Город мал, да много повидал... // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]

2) Прошу также иных соображений и советов, **буде** таковые найдутся. [коллективный. Форум: Проблемы в первом классе (2013)]

Что сможет противопоставить этой катастрофе, **буде** та случится, наше либеральное государство, [Владимир Винников.  (2003).